# Sort a list with lowercase first

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have a file with names and I want to sort them alphabetically but lowercase must be before uppercase.

So if I have for example:

```
Any
ANA
Ana
```

It should be sorted as:

```
Ana
Any
ANA
```

If possible I'd like to achieve this with sort, does it have any options for that?

My current way of sorting:

```
cut -d";" -f2-3 $1 | paste - $1 | sort | cut -f2- >> sorted.txt
```

The line in the file given in the argument `$1` looks like this:

```
12345;Name;Lastname
```

Comment: Hello. Please show us some of your work. With the way you asked it looks like we should google it for you. :)

Comment: @dmadic I've pasted my way current way of sorting :)

Comment: what is the purpose of `paste` here? Ana, Any and ANA are `Name` field in this `.csv` file and you want to sort them?

Comment: The purpose of paste is, that it puts the Name and the Lastname at the beginning, then sorts according to Name and Lastname. Correct, Ana, Any and ANA are Names in .csv file.

Comment: I think first `cut` does what you just said. Running `cut -d";" -f2-3 $1` I get `Name;Last name` but running `paste` after that `cut -d";" -f2-3 $1 | paste - $1` I am getting `Name;Last name  12345;Name;Last name`. which looks like something that we don't really need.

Comment: if we just ran `cut -d";" -f2-3 $1` we would have `Name;Last name` but we need `ID;Name;Last name`. Thats why we paste `Name;Last name` at the beginning, sort it, and then remove it. So we are left with sorted file in format as it was given `ID:Name:Last name`

Comment: Cool, now I see your intention @Lommmp. I was missing the bigger picture. :)

Comment: Problem is, that way of sorting is case-insensitive and I need it to sort lowercase before uppercase.

Comment: `sort` has some great options e.g. `sort -t ';' -k 2,2 < some-csv.log` where `-t ';'` specifies semicolon as delimiter, `-k 2,2` says use only second field, in this case it is the Name. Is this of any benefit to you?

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thank you A TON! :)

Comment: **note:** your natural sort can be effected by your `LC_COLLATE` environment setting. So it can be different on different computers. See [Specify the sort order with LC_COLLATE so lowercase is before uppercase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75341/specify-the-sort-order-with-lc-collate-so-lowercase-is-before-uppercase)

Comment: [Specify the sort order with LC_COLLATE so lowercase is before uppercase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75341/56041), [Why does \[A-Z\] match lowercase letters in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227070/56041), [GNU sort by case-sensitive](https://superuser.com/q/178171/173513), etc.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for: sort -t ';' -k 2,2 < some-csv.log

Big thanks to @dmadic

Answer (score -1):

If your input.txt is something like:

```
Any
ANA
Bill
BOB
Ana
```

and you want your output to be:

```
Ana
Any
Bill
ANA
BOB
```

then, maybe your could try something like:

```
grep -E "[a-z]+" input.txt | sort  > lower.txt
grep -wE "[A-Z]+" input.txt | sort > upper.txt
cat lower.txt upper.txt
```

Comment: Interesting solution but the output in that case should be:

Ana

Any

ANA

Bill

BOB

Comment: As the Q&A's on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) state, `LC_COLLATE` should be overridden.

Answer (score -1):

With Perl you could say:

```
perl -e '
print sort {
    ($ka = (split(/;/, $a))[1]) =~ tr/a-zA-Z/A-Za-z/;
    ($kb = (split(/;/, $b))[1]) =~ tr/a-zA-Z/A-Za-z/;
    $ka cmp $kb;
} <>' input.txt
```